# Strange behavior and memory leaks with NSProgressIndicator and NSOpenPanel in Lion and Mountain Lion

Tags: cocoa, memory-leaks, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion, nsprogressindicator

So I know this may be a hard one to answer but I am experiencing some strange behavior with Mountain and Lion and I was hoping this might ring a bell with some Cocoa gurus.

Inside our app we have a file choosing dialog which is an NSOpenPanel, after the user selects and appropriate file, a NSProgressIndicator pops up and updates using a call to incrementBy while the user's project loads, and then finally an NSWindow pops up with many fun and interesting views (some are NSOpenGLViews).

On Snow Leopard all of this goes down with out a hitch: the file chooser opens, the user selects a file, the file chooser close, THEN the progress meter pops up iterates then the project window pops up.  This is what I have come to expect.

When I tested this on Lion it had a slight variation: the file chooser opens, the user select a file, the file chooser does NOT close, the progress meter either does not pop up or pops up only for a slight moment, the project window pops up and finally the file chooser goes away.  This seems very odd that that the file chooser would linger because it is a modal dialog.

When I finally tested this on Mountain Lion it behaved the same as lion except every now and then the progress meter would pop up and stall on one of the updates and the memory of the application would grow out of control and very rapidly, until the application was using upwards up 3GB and the application crashes.

I was wondering if anyone knows about any changes in Lion/Mountain Lion that might explain this strange behavior.

Comment: What you report suggests you've got the sandbox turned on (dodgy open panel, memory growth, stalls). If so turn it off. Did that help? If so and you need the sandbox go search & ask on the Apple developer forums.

Comment: Hmm no we don't have that sandbox turned on, in fact the app isn't even currently codesigned which Mountain Lion was not at all happy about.